# giving ID to multiple SVGs in raphael

Tags: javascript, svg, raphael

I have multiple SVGs which I want to add an ID. The problem is that they are created automatically by the Raphael object. 
Is there an easy way of adding ID to the Raphael paper? ( note that there are multiple papers)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All objects in Raphael return a shape element, and you can use the [`node`](http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Element.node) property to get access to the raw element. From there its fairly trivial to give the element an ID.

For example, to create a rectangle with an ID:

```
paper.rect(0, 0, 300, 300, 0).attr({fill: "orange", stroke: "none"}).node.setAttribute('id', 'myElement');
```

And a working fiddle to see it in action: http://jsfiddle.net/CwmZr/1/

Note that Raphael may not always use SVG. In older versions of IE, it will use VML, so `node` will likely refer to a VML element, not an SVG element.

**EDIT**:

If you want to set the ID of the paper object (the `<svg />` element), you could do something like this:

```
var paper = //get the paper object
paper.canvas.setAttribute('id', 'mySvgElement');
```

Comment: Is there an easy way of adding ID to the **Raphael paper**?
That means <svg id = "">, but in a dynamic way.

Comment: @AlmogDubin ah, now I see. Yes. Updated.